Find and compare folder modification times
I ask for help
It is necessary to compare the date and time of folder modification and if the folder has not been modified for more than 4 hours then echo 1 if it has been modified then 0
I found out the date and time of the change
FOR %A IN ("C:\Program Files") DO @ECHO=%~tA


The Windows Command Processor cmd.exe processing a batch file is the only script interpreter installed by default on Windows which has built-in no support for time difference calculations. The usage of a PowerShell script for that task would be much better. However, look on the answers on Find out if file is older than 4 hours in Batch file if you really want to code that in a batch file without the help of other script interpreters like PowerShell or Windows Script Host.
